# Where is a good place to store online music which can be accessible by html and javascript?

Tags: software

I asked a similar question in the stack overflow area.  I got no response, but was hoping maybe here other musicians may have had similar problems and may have found a solution.

I am presently writing a touch interactive ebook teaching chord and interval theory for guitar.  I have gone to great lengths to record and master each note of each fret of my guitar in order to make 100's of interactive chord and interval diagrams that will play the notes when a user taps a diagram so they can hear the sound of any given type of chord.  The coding is coming along nicely, however, I have run into a snag, in that, while I'm developing this, I cannot find a good place to put my mp3 files online where I can access them from within my html/javascript.  I need a host so that I can accurately test each diagram as they become interactive.

Most cloud storage sites like google drive, dropbox, and several others store the files in such a way that they cannot be directly accessed by a web browser.

The following is a google drive link to one of the mp3 files. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QHq_oPha0yamJ0Z2U0UWVwNDA/view?usp=sharing

Does any hosting site exist where I can put my mp3 files online and access them through a url that ends in .mp3? {example:  http://www.mymusicfiles.com/myown.mp3}

I apologize if this is not asked in entirely the right place, but the project itself is very music and theory oriented.

Comment: Soundcloud is a great way to share your music.

Comment: I would have recommended checking what your ISP provides, but fewer and fewer are offering personal webspace.  Comcast is shutting down their service (which I'd been using partly to host files the way you want) after 20 years.  [bleep] you, Comcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Github Pages and Git. Github stores all files in raw, javascript usable form, and this works for all file types as far as I know.

To push files to Github you'll have to make a repository for your project, download Git, and push files to the repository. It's a little frustrating at first and might take an hour or two to figure out, but it is definitely worth it as it is free.

[Here's a Git tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2) to get you started.

Another plus to Git and Github is that you can do all of your coding and file loading and stuff all in the same place. Even if you don't want to use Github Pages for your website you can still just make a repository and host your files and file loaders there.

One final note is that if you're using a website builder like weebly, mp3 file hosting should be built in. For weebly, as an example, just go into the "Edit HTML and CSS" section and upload an the mp3 as an asset. Even though that's meant for images and such, mp3 files hosted there will work fine too. However in this case, unless you're actually using weebly to build your site, don't make a weebly website simply for the purpose of hosting your files, as that's against their TOS.

Comment: Superdoggy - policy on Stack Exchange is to avoid unnecessary stuff like thanks, signatures etc. We just want posts to either contain a question or an answer. The rest just adds noise.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this - can you please tell me why? I see absolutely nothing wrong with my answer, as it's a highly effective solution which I have tried and succeeded with in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AmazonS3. It is affordable and easy to setup. You can store them there and access them directly, AWS will serve them for you.